# Can I opt-out of specific Windows updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-update

I have some older Windows 7 and 10 laptops which cannot afford to have a slowdown as I've heard is caused by the Meltdown and Spectre patches. (One of them is barely able to run on its existing hardware, the other one is mostly workable but can't really afford a slowdown, and the Win 10 laptop had the bare minimum specs to support the OS and it's really showing it.) Is there a way I can leave Windows updates enabled, but explicitly opt out of these two patches?

To be clear, I'm looking for a general solution of opting out of specific patches, while leaving regular updates automatically enabled.

Comment: use WSUS to approve updates if you use several devices

Comment: If you're downvoting, please comment so I know how to improve my question. Also remember that downvotes don't mean "I don't agree with what you're trying to do." They mean "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: you did no research otherwise had found WSUS on your own: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-manage-updates-wsus

Comment: Course I did research: there's question here about explicitly opting out of driver updates, which are through the same update mechanism. And that particular question said: yes, you can. And how in the world would I know that "WSUS" even exists? Googling for "can I skip a windows update?" shows me one answer for Win 7, and a whole bunch of "it got stuck, help" or "how do I defer" or "can I interrupt it?"

Comment: I get the WSUS link as 3rd item in google when I search for "manage Windows updates" 

Comment: Google search results are tailored to your previously tracked behavior. I also don't want to "manage" them -- I just want to not apply this one in specific, so it's not the search term I would (or did) use.

Comment: you want to managed/approve updates. 4 users think you did no research effort and all 4 are right. I'm out here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - to be fair, it's not obviously apparent from descriptions of WSUS that it can do what is being asked for here. I wouldn't expect to use a tool that "enables information technology administrators to deploy the latest Microsoft product updates" or "helps distribute updates, fixes, and other types of releases available from Microsoft Update"  (as described by the top two google results for the tool) to *prevent* an update being installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can [turn off updates](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-windows-update-in-windows-10) completely, which is *very* bad idea.  You can also [defer updates](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-defer-windows-10-updates) for a while as well, which also isn't highly recommended.

However, you cannot skip an update.  This is the update model Microsoft has chosen.  In my opinion, this is the best choice as well.  The general public was not properly updating their PCs, leaving them vulnerable.

Now as for the Meltdown and Spectre patch slowing down your computer, the slowdown will more than likely be hardly noticeable, if at all, for almost everyone.  I have the patches on my devices and even on the low end PCs, I see no discernible difference in performance.

Comment: [PC World](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3245742/components-processors/microsoft-tests-show-spectre-patches-drag-down-performance-on-older-pcs.html) had an article today showing that Microsoft's own benchmark tests showed marked decreases in performance for systems that were not running modern silicon. My laptops are 5+ years old and were not high end when purchased. I'd rather not take the risk, especially since other articles indicate that this particular update doesn't create a backup point and is very hard to roll back even with a full windows reinstall.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas PC World isn’t a reliable publication.  That article is also trash, it makes claims, but doesn’t provide any data to compare before and after the patch was installed.  I can only assume that’s because their benchmark approach is invalid.

Comment: MS does have the Windows Update Diagnostic app to block specific updates.

Comment: OK, fine, so maybe PCMag is trash. [Here's](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2018/01/09/understanding-the-performance-impact-of-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations-on-windows-systems/) the blog post from microsoft saying the same thing, where they say "With Windows 8 and Windows 7 on older silicon (2015-era PCs with Haswell or older CPU), we expect most users to notice a decrease in system performance." My laptops are much older than 2015.

Comment: You are still going to run into the fact every update released after KB4056892 will include the vulnerability fixes for those exploits.  Windows 7 does monthly updates, so the vulnerabilities fixes will be included in next months updates also, so you can't really avoid the fixes to these exploits.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I just looked at a variety of benchmarks online.  For the most part, performance is not affected.with some performance metrics taking a *slight* and in some cases performance has been *improved*.

Answer (score 2):

First, [**actual tests** comparing before and after performance for the Meltdown/Spectre vulnerability patch show little observable slowdown](https://www.techspot.com/article/1554-meltdown-flaw-cpu-performance-windows/). That said, as of Jan 9, 2018, [MS has **withdrawn that patch for use on machines with AMD CPU**](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/01/bad-docs-and-blue-screens-make-microsoft-suspend-spectre-patch-for-amd-machines/) due to BSD issues.

There are some ways to prevent specific updates for Windows 10 (some of these may also work on Windows 7). First, defer Windows updates to prevent automatic installation.

- [Using a third-party tool such as O&O ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10), "Activate deferring of updates."

[image: ShutUp10 defer updates]

- [Using *Regedit*, set all internet connections as metered.](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-ethernet-connection-metered-windows-10) Open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost`, take ownership of the key and "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects", and set the value for each connection type to *2* (set back to *1* to revert).

After the update *list* has loaded in Windows, you can then **[download a Microsoft tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/223864/how-to-uninstall-and-block-updates-and-drivers-on-windows-10/) to [block (re)installation of problematic patches](https://www.howtogeek.com/223864/how-to-uninstall-and-block-updates-and-drivers-on-windows-10/)**.

You can also allow an update to be installed, then uninstall it and prevent its reinstallation with the [Windows Update Diagnostic app](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab).

Completely blocking Windows updates is not recommended, becuse security patches would not be installed.

Comment: Worth pointing out, while you can defer the most recent patch (which is the patch that contains the fix), uninstalled patches are rolled into the next patch.  So on Windows 7+ that basically means never patching again.  There hasn’t been another patch day, hence, why I feel obligated to point this out

Comment: @user3169 - Last weeks update will be included in the next patch.

Comment: MS *does* release occasional stand-alone patches, e.g.*Security update for Adobe Flash Player: January 9, 2018*, but, as @Ramhound states, MS tends to roll up a batch of patches into updates, so some may be foisted on you though the original, stand-alone, was blocked. Unlike Linux patches, MS tends to be all-or-nothing.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I think the best I can do is to implement a one week delay in updating so any major issues can be understood.

Comment: @Ramhound Well today's update is only "2018-01 Security and Quality Rollup for .Net Framework..." (KB4055532). It does not include the issues from last week's update.

Comment: @user3169 - I am talking about the cumulative updates, not the stand-only fixes.  The Meltdown and Spectre, are part of the cumulative updates, so the next cumulative update will include those fixes if your system doesn't have the current cumulative update installed.  You are trying to argue a point, when I am trying to educate you, I am not really interested in a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do it in Windows 10.
In windows 7, when you go to Windows Updates and click on the link to show detailed list of updates, you can right-click on the specific update you do not want and select **Hide Update**.
This way you can Hide/not install specific updates.